# what vehicle disk brake diameter 220 mm tickness 10 mm

Tags: brakes, trailer

I have a caravan with unknown disk brakes.
The disk is 220 mm in diameter and 10 mm tick.
What vehicle are these from?

Comment: What is the bolt pattern on them? (distance between studs and stud count)

Comment: Also, 10mm is only 1cm ... this leads me to believe it's off of a motorcycle ... it would never be on a car, that's for sure ... way too thin. I'm also wondering what you mean by "caravan" ... I was thinking "van made by Chrysler" when I first read it, but wondering now if it is a language translation problem ...

Comment: ["Caravan" in British English](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/caravan) is what we would call a camping trailer, @Paulster2. I'd guess that was what was meant here.

Comment: @JoshCaswell - Thanks for clarification. Makes a lot more sense now.

Comment: What make model year is the caravan? Are they hydraulic or cable operated?

Comment: its not a motorcycle brake disk, those things are never that thickness.  normally a bike brake disk is around 3-7mm thick and have much shallower offsets.

Comment: I've added the 'trailer' tag to clarify, as a caravan is a type of trailer...

Comment: Is 10cm the factory width or the current worn width?

Answer (score 1):

Caravan and trailor manufacturers use a variety of brands for brakes, axles and hubs stubs and rims.

These could be surplus car items or purpose made for trailers. For example Trojan http://www.trojan.co.nz/stub-kits-disc-c-23_26.html

Some details about the make,  model, year, and country of origin of your caravan might help identify them.

Also photos of the disc, hubs calipers and even rims might help.